# c++ copy-until algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a function that is expected to receive a list of individual characters through a `const char *`. If I had to copy each character to a `vector<char>`, what would be the best (i.e.: most efficient) way to perform the operation?

I have thought about `copy` in **algorithm**, not sure if it's the more "elegant" solution:

```
void
example
    (const char * const s)
{
    copy(s, s+strlen(s), myvector.begin())
}
```

(hope that, given my "personal" indenting style, the code is still readable for you)

But I'm sure the STL implements something that allows me to copy *until* a null character is found in the string.

(If you wonder why I'm receiving a `const char *`, well, that's the type the compiler creates when the user makes use of a temporal variable, and my function is expected to be called like `example("fvh")`. Alternative solutions are welcomed)

Thanks in advance. Best regards,
Kalrish

### EDIT:

After trying what @ipc and @juanchopanza said, I feel stupid: it works like a charm.

Not still sure if I will lose performance, but, in any case, the compiler makes the implicit conversion, and it's pure C++, so it is definitely the way to go.

Thanks a lot, and sorry. Good luck,
Kalrish

Comment: If the signature is `void example(const std::string& s)`, you are still able to call it like `example("fvh")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `std::string`, and the `std::vector::assign` method.

```
void example(const std::string& s)
{
    myvector.assign(s.begin(), s.end()):
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I would have answered my own question, but I haven't enough reputation, so I have edited my original post instead. And, thanks again, for using `vector::assign`: less headers, native functions. Thanks!

Comment: @Kalrish your method is OK too. The only problem is that you have to be sure that the vector is large enough to hold all the characters that will be copied. And it is larger than the input message, it will contain part of the previous contents towards the end. So `assign` fixes that. The potential overhead of a `string` construction` can be eliminated by using `std::vector::assign` with `strlen`, i.e. a combination of your method and mine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a copy until.

Here is a copy until `'\0'` however:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct str_copy_iterator {
  bool at_end;
  char const* ptr;
  char operator*() const { return *ptr; }
  typedef char value_type;
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
  typedef char* pointer;
  typedef char& reference;
  typedef std::output_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  str_copy_iterator():at_end(true) {}
  str_copy_iterator(char const* p):at_end(!p||!*p), ptr(p) {}
  str_copy_iterator& operator++() {
    ++ptr;
    at_end = !*ptr;
    return *this;
  }
  str_copy_iterator operator++(int) {
    str_copy_iterator tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
  }
  bool operator!=( str_copy_iterator const& o ) const {
     return !(*this == o);
  }
  bool operator==( str_copy_iterator const& o ) const {
    if (at_end)
      return o.at_end;
    if (o.at_end)
      return false;
    return ptr == o.ptr;
  }
};
int main() {
   const char* bob = "hello world!";
   char buff[100] = {};
   std::copy(str_copy_iterator(bob), str_copy_iterator(), &buff[0] );
   std::cout << buff << "\n";
}
```

extending the `str_copy_iterator` into a generic `iterator_until` wrapper is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you too, but I think I'm better going with @juanchopanza's answer. Sorry for making you write that piece of code.